# how to query out mysql record which store values in one column

Tags: mysql

I use breezingform for joomla to create web form, which store user input records in database as below:

**forms_records**

```
id  | form  | name          
24    19       kpi          
25    19       kpi
```

**forms_subrecords**

```
id   | element  | record    | description  |  value  | type
101     406        24          month         2015-01   calendar
102     407        24          east          30%       text
103     408        24          south         35%       text
104     409        24          north         50%       text
105     410        24          west          25%       text
106     406        25          month         2015-02   calendar
107     407        25          east          45%       text
108     408        25          south         35%       text
109     409        25          north         15%       text
110     410        25          west          5%        text
```

I tried do it in:
1. get record id first

```
SELECT id FROM forms_records WHERE form='19'
```

2. get subrecords value

> ```
> SELECT s.value 
> from forms_subrecords AS s 
> WHERE s.record 
>   IN (SELECT id FROM forms_records WHERE form='19')
> ```

the result are 10 rows with one column,

```
2015-01
30%
35%
50%
25%
2015-02
45%
35%
15%
5%
```

but what I want are 2 rows with 5 columns:

```
2015-01 30% 35% 50% 25% 
2015-02 45% 35% 15% 5%
```

anyone can help or give some hints?

Comment: thanks Alex, I found the question messed up, just took a screenshot and tried to upload.

Comment: finally, alexander gave a answer here.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060426/how-to-get-two-columns-from-mysql-dynamic-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060426/how-to-get-two-columns-from-mysql-dynamic-table)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Pivot would work. Hope it helps.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional case expression together with an aggregate max function to do this:

```
SELECT 
  max(case when s.description = 'month' then s.value end) col1,
  max(case when s.description = 'east'  then s.value end) col2,
  max(case when s.description = 'south' then s.value end) col3,
  max(case when s.description = 'north' then s.value end) col4,
  max(case when s.description = 'west'  then s.value end) col5
FROM forms_subrecords AS s 
WHERE s.record 
  IN (SELECT id FROM forms_records WHERE form='19')
GROUP BY 
  record
```

A sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a028/8) gives this output:

```
|    COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
|---------|------|------|------|------|
| 2015-01 |  30% |  35% |  50% |  25% |
| 2015-02 |  45% |  35% |  15% |   5% |
```