# How to get two columns from mysql dynamic table

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

I have a dynamic table which created by breezing form

```
>   id  record  element title   name    type    value
>   6131    627 6448    Date    date    Calendar    2017-05-15
>   6132    627 6453    Number  num Text    4
>   6129    626 6448    Date    date    Calendar    2017-05-12
>   6130    626 6453    Number  num Text    3
>   6127    625 6448    Date    date    Calendar    2017-05-10
>   6128    625 6453    Number  num Text    1
```

[image: dynamic table]

I want to create a chart by joomla-plotalot components which ask 2 columns result within one select query,like

```
> 2017-05-15    1 
> 2017-05-12    3 
> 2017-05-10    4
```

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution. Join the table to itself using subqueries with aliases.

```
SELECT 
  d.`value` AS `date`,
  n.`value` AS `num`
FROM
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM MyTable WHERE `name`='date') AS d
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `record`, `value` FROM MyTable WHERE `name`='num') AS n
  USING (`record`);
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (SELECT record, value FROM jo17_facileforms_subrecords WHERE name='date'' at line 4

Comment: @user3009410, I tried to run the query on my own MySQL server. It works. Please try again. Note, so words as `name`, `value`, `date` etc. would be enclosed by ` ... `.

Comment: Yes, it works now! thank you so much, I have been looking the answer for months.